# jQuery new syntax?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery statement in a project code, which was written by someone else. Can someone explain what the meaning and purpose of this usage is? Thanks!

```
$.hello = {};

$.hello.callFunction();
```

Comment: This was closed by the community for being off-topic, and better suited to StackOverflow. Might be worth posting there, though please post questions here that are definitely Salesforce related!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line would be adding an empty object called "hello" to the jQuery context. (So far so good).

The second line throws an error as evidenced by this jsbin: 
http://jsbin.com/qelaze/1/edit

In face, if you add this between the two:

```
console.log(typeof $.hello.callFunction);
```

The output is "undefined".

Looks to me like someone was starting something, and didn't finish.